# PDFStream getBytes adds braces and numbers so replace doesnt work

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

PdfStream bytes array adds parentheses and negative float values in between due to which replace doesn't work. Can you please help me on this?

PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) object;
byte[] data = stream.getBytes();
String replacedData = new String(data).replace("DCC ID: XXX-X", "TEST ID: 123-4");

```
    [(TEST ID:)0.5 ( X)-15.3 (X)-15.2 (X)18.4 (-X)-15.2 (X)-15.3 (X)-15.2 (X)-15.3 (X)-15.3 (X)]TJ
```

Comment: The parentheses delineate the individual strings. The negative numbers are kerns. You can't expect to run a simple text search-and-replace on a PDF content stream. PDF content streams are concerned with the layout of letters on the page, not the semantic content.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, John. Is there any other way to replace text while copying over one pdf into another which also has images?